# Why Dart's package manager is called pub?

Tags: dart

Just that: Why is the package manager called pub?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you play darts in a pub. :)

Comment: XD I broke my mind thinking on an acronym, abbreviation or sth XD

Comment: Hahaha same ! I thought it was something like "Package Update/Build".

Answer (score 2):

It also lets you have the "lish" command :-)